# Name change for DSP.SE?

Tags: discussion

Based on [this question](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1321/80), there are many who feel that a image processing and computer vision should be given higher visibility on this site.  The separate proposal for a CV/IP site has not succeeded, so I am asking the community whether we want to incorporate some / all of those words in our site title?

We may be able to convince the SE gods that this is good, provided we come up with a decent proposal and that proposal has good support.

The possibilities are:

- No change.
- Keep `dsp.stackexchange.com` but title the site **Signal and Image Processing**
- Change the URL to `sip.stackexchange.com` and title the site **Signal and Image Processing**.
- Keep the URL `dsp.stackexchange.com` and change the title to `<<insert your title here>>`.
- Change the URL to `<<insert your preference here>>` and change the title to `<<insert your title here>>`.

Please read [this post](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1053) about name changing.  Main points to note:

- Sites with `&` in the title are generally frowned upon, but not impossible.
- This name change is a one-time thing. No redos.

Also please read [this post on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/why-the-name-signal-image-and-video-processing) made during the site's formation.

Answer (score 11):

I think sticking to the way things are now is not a bad idea. A good example is the [IEEE signal processing society](http://www.signalprocessingsociety.org). You got many sub-fields that just fall under the same head denomination, but defined with common technical interests as [Technical Committees](http://www.signalprocessingsociety.org/technical-committees/list/) that focus on various signal processing related activities.

Maybe something with the same `dsp.stackexchange.com` URL and the same **Signal Processing** title but with additional description down with the various subfields, maybe something like what [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) has done:

> Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization. It's 100% free, no registration required.

Comment: Wise, up to Forensics. However, Trans. PAMI is not in IEEE signal processing society

Comment: No, but IEEE Trans. Image Processing is part of IEEE-SP.

Answer (score 7):

I think we better change the name into **Signal and Image Processing**.
I'm not sure on the URL, But I think I would go with `sip.stackexchange.com`.

The reasoning is simple, many of the questions deals with `image-processing`, [the most popular tag on this site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing).

Yet most of them are by beginners. And why is that?

Simple, if you're advanced in the field of Image Processing, you don't go to **Signal Processing** forums.

So the name change might bring into the community advanced Image Processing people which now will see this as their home.

With time, we'll see more advanced questions on the topic and larger community.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited this a little.  The `image-processing` tag is actually the most popular on the site, as far as I can see. That's a very good indication that we should move in that direction.

Comment: I think *Signal and Image Processing* is a fine name, but I would be wary of eliminating the DSP.SE address. If a new address such as `sip.stackexchange.com` was used, is it acceptable to keep `dsp.stackexchange.com` as well?

Comment: I would be wary of changing the DSP subdomain, although it is possible to setup redirections. Changing the title and possibly description of the DSP SE site would probably be enough to reflect the content of the questions that are discussed currently on the site.

Comment: A good solution for the URL thing can be having `dsp.stackexchange.com` move visitors to `sip.stachexchange.com`. This will keep all the SEO efforts relevant.

Comment: Keep in mind that http://signals.stackexchange.com is already the official name for the site. http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1/first-up-what-to-call-this-site?lq=1

Comment: Isn't an image just a 2-dimensional signal?

Comment: +1 for Signal and Image Processing, -1 for `sip.stackexchange.com`.  DSP includes image processing already.

Comment: SIP means something entirely different though to people who work with telecomms.

Answer (score 4):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/ apparently kept the  base url `stats`, while named Cross Validated. `dsp` is widely  indexed, I would not  modify it.

Since the "name change is a one-time thing", I'd suggest to give it some time. Although quite long, I propose "**Signal Processing, Image Analysis**". I  make a difference between:

- processing: data in, data out,
- analysis: data in, features out.

I genuinely believe people look for "analysis" too. I have experienced that it is difficult to explain what we do. Everybody "understands" mathematics, statistics, physics. Those are genuine "science" names. Our  community misses a real name, with greek roots. One can forge "**[dedomenology](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/10001/12527)**", from [dedomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_%28Euclid%29), for data, or information given. But the world is not ready for that.

And now for a completely different proposal: I have been using the acronym **SIVA** for **S**ignal, **I**mage, **V**ideo **A**nalysis. But one can read **S**amples, **I**nformation, **V**ision. This may remind us of the Hindu pantheon god, both a creator and a destructor, which is what we do with data and noise. Only for the shared ideas.

Comment: This writing is too distinctive and implies Signal Processing and Image Analysis as Image Processing is not here. Most courses on University are called Image Processing. Just like Signal Processing includes Signal Analysis this i the term used. Though I agree with you that processing is a step in Analysis. Yet it is not our job to fix this, our job is to bring advanced people from the worlds of Image Processing, and this is the way.

Comment: By the way, Maybe Signal and Image Processing and Computer Vision would be the perfect things.