# Ten Year anniversary blog post

Tags: discussion

I am preparing to share a blog blurb for the upcoming blog post next week with our Marketing team. We're going to follow the template from last quarter's celebratory post. You can [see the format here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/19/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/). Below you'll find the draft I'm putting together. It's not final and could use some help from you all! Please make any suggested edits and revisions in your answers and I'll update the text here based on answers with the most votes. The **deadline** for this is **Sept. 15, 2021**. Please

Here's the text:

> [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/)
>
> A site with high-quality answers for practitioners of the art and science of signal, image and video processing. Questions about theory, practice, algorithm recommendations and debugging, or conceptual topics are welcomed.
>
> – [Most Upvoted Question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/374/river-detection-in-text) / Most Popular Tag: [image-processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing)

Comment: For a long time I have said the name of the site should be changed into Signal and Image Processing. See https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1378.

Answer (score 2):

The "most popular tag" is misleading: While image processing most definitely is a prominent topic here, some other fields get more traction, but aren't as consistently tagged with [field-name](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-name).

Also, as someone who's doing statistical signal processing: Linking to "Most Upvoted Question" makes little sense, you're just showing a question that go a high number of votes very early. It tells readers nearly nothing about the things this community talks about.

"Most Frequent" would make more sense, but that's just the ones that gets most frequently marked as original to a duplicate question – so, a bit of newbie-catcher assortment of questions! So, also not a good representative of our question pool.

I'd propose that we curate a list of questions with the highest *upvotes per unit of time*, where we weigh upvotes exponentially decreasing into the past.

(NB: Yes, this is a general remark on the options in question sorting offered by stackexchange – aside from the "Newest" listing, they're basically uninteresting, unless you're looking for fresh drama, i.e. "Active". It's just that the footline in your excerpt illustrates that very nicely by not properly representing the site.)

Thank you for this, by the way!

Comment: I agree with what you said and that's the kind of direction I was hoping for from the community earlier. If you have any suggestions, I _may_ be able to make a change - no promises though!

Comment: @JuanM Thank you so much for being so kind! I must admit I'm not good enough with data explorer to build something like what I described above right now.