# (Updated) Design for Signal Processing Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, design

Thank you to everyone who took the time to review and provide feedback on the [Signal Processing Site Design](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/design-for-signal-processing-stack-exchange). Based on the post’s feedback, we created a second option for the site’s color scheme. We explored a number of color palettes and feel these two options are the strongest.

**I’ve posted both color options below as separate answers, please vote for your favorite this week.**

We’d like to start building this soon, so please let us know what you think. Thanks again for your feedback so far, and thanks for being such a great community!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Blue / Green**

[image]

Comment: I really like this design - would wear it proudly on my t-shirt ;) Great job guys!

Comment: This looks nice for the most part. I would only echo a commenter from the previous design in indicating that the badge icons look very strange.

Comment: This is the one for me. :-) @JasonR : I'm going to make believe the badge icons are tie fighters. :-)

Comment: Thank you everyone, we'll go with this color scheme. The badge icons are a challenge at such a small size, though I'll take a look at them as well!

Answer (score 2):

**Red / Orange**

[image]