# New Site Design Live!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations! As you can see, the new site design is live. Thank you for your feedback [here](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/design-for-signal-processing-stack-exchange) and [here](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/updated-design-for-signal-processing-stack-exchange). As you can see, I updated the color scheme to blue/green. I also explored a few alternatives for the badge icon but ultimately didn’t come up with anything better. If you have a suggestion, please leave it in the comments.

Along with the site design, the newsletter and chat room will also adopt the new site theme. If find any design/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with `design` and `bug`.

Thanks and congrats on the new site theme!

Comment: Looks good. One thing I notice is that the header (with the logo, questions, tags, users, etc.) is noticeably taller than the equivalent on other sites like SO. Is this by design?

Comment: @JasonR Well [not](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) [all](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/) [sites](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/) but yes it's a bit taller than Stack Overflow by design.

Comment: Amazing job! Thanks to all SE guys for your work, and to DSP users for your input!

Comment: What about including something about Image Processing in the site name? We talked about it and it seemed most people were pro doing it.

Comment: YAY ! Finally, super cool design.

Comment: nice. (added text to make this long enough).

Comment: Great stuff! Thank-you @TedGoas for the update! :-)

Comment: whoa that logo's cool.  The bars aren't the same width though, as they were in http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/q/1402/29

Comment: I love the logo.

Comment: @endolith oops! I think this is an artifact of two different designers working on this :/ They _should_ be the same width, I will update. Thanks!

Comment: Looks very nice, just saw the logo in a hot network question and it's nicely distinct from all the other logos. Great job also with the overall design!

Comment: @TedGoas Fixed!

Answer (score 12):

Looks good, though there might be one piece missing?

[image]

The "reputation" text color for accepted answers should probably be a little lighter (or different from the current blue).

The "answers" one seems to get it right.

[image]

---

Just noticed another one: when a question has an accepted answer, the text under the dot showing the number of answers cannot be read.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out! I just pushed a fix for these, let me know if these still seem broken in a few hours.

Comment: @TedGoas Cool! Thanks for this! Much appreciated. Will check later today.

Comment: @TedGoas : I'm still seeing the reputation rep up value being green in a green box on accepted answers. A check of the CSS in Chrome dev tools says the selected color is being over-ridden somewhere else. Erk. And when I go back to it, the "Reputation" part of the profile is missing completely.

Comment: Hi Peter, how about now? Sorry, this is one piece of the UI that's notoriously difficult to fix and verify!

Comment: @TedGoas That's working now! Thank-you for your patience. :-)

Comment: Great, good to hear!