# How much of Image Processing does Signal Processing Handle?

Tags: discussion

sorry to make this meta post sound like a domain problem. I'd have asked on the main site if that were (only) the case. I'm interested in how relavent DIP, NIP and CV are here.

This community seems to be the only place where I can ask Image Processing related queries. I hope this is the right place to contribute that content.

I've made a trello board of topics I'd like to study: https://trello.com/b/3bLroaxd

Images and Signals are equivalent? I'm not sure. I know vectors can be involved in both. So, maybe the same analysis tools could be used in both domains. A quick search validates my intuition:

> **Image processing** is a method to convert an image into digital form and perform some operations on it, in order to get an enhanced image or to extract some useful information from it. It is a type of **signal dispensation** in which input is image, like video frame or photograph and output may be image or characteristics associated with that image. Usually Image Processing system includes treating images as two dimensional signals while applying already set **signal processing** methods to them.

According to @Deve from [this relavent thread](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/should-there-be-a-separate-image-processing-computer-vision-se-site),

> It's no problem if there are "shadow communities" inside DSP.

And I don't believe there's any merit in  proposing a DIP stackexchenge at Area51. At this point, even if I get my friends, classmates (and beyond) on it, I believe Robert will just close it after community review, as he very consistently does. I just want to ask one thing:

**(Q) *Do the topics of DIP fit in DSP?***

Hope this question will be well received. I'm happy with whatever the response.

Answer (score 6):

There was an attempt to set up an Area 51 Computer Vision site, but it has since [been deleted for lack of support.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832/image-processing-and-computer-vision)

I personally believe that signal processing is an all-encompassing field, and that image processing (or computer vision) is well inside its boundaries.

Comment: If that's the case we need a better name as the way things are currently, we have a lot of image processing related questions yet little number of people with knowledge on the field.

Comment: @Royi We’ve already had that try to change the name and it never went anywhere.

Comment: When we had that try, could you shed light of what really happened behind the scene? Who opposed it?